# Scheduling PaceMaker resources based on Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, pacemaker

I would like to have a PaceMaker cloned resource be scheduled on all cluster nodes that have at least one instance of a specific Kubernetes pod running.

Background: I want to run a Kubernetes cluster that has several
ingress proxies running as DaemonSet on specific nodes. I am using PaceMaker to distribute public IP addresses amongst those nodes, and I want to have PaceMaker move an address to another node that is "active" when the ingress proxy is stopped on a node.

Best I have come up is to look at the running pods and depending on the state, set a node attribute in PaceMaker that makes it schedule all IP addresses on nodes where the proxy is running.

Is this the best way achieve this? And is there an existing solution for this?

Note: I am not looking for the "best" solution for load balancing/ingress, I am looking for the best solution to solve this scenario.

Comment: https://metallb.universe.tf/concepts/layer2/ Not sure if this matches your intent, but I used this in the past for floating IPs.